# Is there google analytic SDK available for Roku SG?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

We want to implement google analytic by SDK in our Roku SG application. We searched about google analytic sdk for Roku SG, we did not find sdk. Is google analytic sdk available for Roku SG?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether there is an official SDK from Google, but here is seemingly a decent library: https://github.com/veeta-tv/roku-gamp.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you have experience of working with REST API on Roku.

1. You can implement Google analytics all by yourself by making the HTTP requests as in Google Measurement protocol(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) or
2. Integrate mParticle, a 3 party SDK:  https://github.com/mParticle/mparticle-roku-sdk